# Amazon DynamoDB Driver

Tags: java, netbeans, driver, amazon-dynamodb

I'm probably way off the mark here but I am just starting to exploring DynamoDB and I was wondering if there is a driver available for it? I currently use netbeans and glassfish and I'm trying to setup a connection pool like I do with MySQL and connectorJ.

In netbeans to setup a Database connection I go to:

Databases > New Connection

I'm then prompted to use either one of the pre-registered Drivers (Oracle, ConnectorJ etc.) or add a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any glassfish/javaEE/hibernate style drivers. You can use the AWS SDK, which even has a [Hibernate-ish persistence model](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaSDKHighLevel.html).

Comment: Thanks, I have been using both the API and the Java style OPM and much like the rest of the Amazon API its really clean and easy. The reason I was asking was to create a connection pool from the glassfish server. Obviously its expensive to create a new connection for every query to the db so I was wondering how you would go about creating a connection pool for Dynamo.

Comment: we just create a static/singleton. The java dynamo wrapper seems to be very expensive, though, the average roundtrip for a read is 60ms.